# Find item from Viewbag.List

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

My controller code is as follows

```
ViewBag.Districts = (from a in _dbContext.DISTRICTS 
                     select new ComboItem { 
                                            ID = a.DISTRICT_ID, 
                                            Name = a.DISTRICT_NAME 
                                          }
                     ).ToList();
```

My Razor View code as follows

```
@foreach (var dist in ViewBag.Districts)
{
    if (item.DISTRICT_ID == dist.ID)
    {
        @dist.Name
    }
}
```

Is there a way I can find item in ViewBag.Districts like `ViewBag.Districts.where(m=>m.ID==item.DISTRICT_ID.`
or linq expression so that i can avoid looping.
Anyone helps me greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is `item` in `item.DISTRICT_ID`?

Comment: Don't put presentation or business logic into your views. Filter the contents **before** you pass it to the view and just consume them there

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Viewbag` is dynamic so compiler won't be able to identify its actual Type, so you need explicit type cast like this to work with Enumerable methods:-

```
((IEnumerable<ComboItem>)ViewBag.Districts).Where(x => x.ID == item.DISTRICT_ID);
```

I am assuming you want to use this in your `View`, Also the `foreach` loop you have posted won't work without explicit casting:-

```
@foreach (var dist in (IEnumerable<ComboItem>)ViewBag.Districts)
{
    if (item.DISTRICT_ID == dist.ID)
    {
        @dist.Name
    }
}
```

Comment: It would work even without casting but intellisense would not work with dynamic object.

Comment: @JenishRabadiya - Nope it's not going to work in View.